# Login as Singleton class

Tags: authentication, singleton, design-patterns

I have a direct question: Is a good pratice use Singleton pattern to control a class responsable for Login tasks, or another pattern is more appropriated? Or do not exist a patter to do this kind os issue?

Thanks.

Comment: I have edited the answer a little bit, please check edit.

Answer (score 3):

Few people use singletons these days as they are almost becoming anti-patterns. I would recommend to learn Dependency Injection *(DI)*.

With DI you can register the object you wish to use as singleton with a container and that container will serve or give that object to all other objects that need it. Of course you can register the object as a singleton *- but not the usual singleton -* and the container will guarantee that all objects which need it will receive the same instance.

Nevertheless, if you are building a small application then It would be better to use the Singleton pattern and avoid DI.

Jon Skeet has a very **[nice article](http://csharpindepth.com/articles/general/singleton.aspx)** about Singleton pattern or if you are using Java then you could use Enumerations to implement it, look implementations techniques on Google.

Answer (score 1):

The singleton pattern is used when you have to prevent the creation of more than one instance of the same class. I do not really see the situation in which a login class should only have one instance so i would say using this pattern for a login class is overkill.

Then again, introducing a DI framework when you only need a simple singleton... now thats overkill :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no. There's no 'best' or 'worse' practise.

Just do it, if using a singleton makes it easier to test and if the approach will get you to the pub earlier than learning and implementing DI just for the purposes of login.